# Non-deterministic `segmentation falut` using `#pragma parallel for ...`

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am new to `C` and discovered `openMP` as a way to execute an intensive part of my program in parallel. I have custom `struct` that stores an `int`, `float` and `**int` pointer. I am passing it to the `#pragma omp parallel for` as a `firstprivate` but I get a `segmentation fault`. The problem is that the `segmentation fault` does not occur *deterministically* every time I run the program. Sometimes it will not even occur at all. This makes me think that it is a data race of some kind, but I am not sure.

In more detail, the following MWE, which I have not tested should reproduce the scenario in which I am encountering the non-deterministic `segmentation fault`. Since, it is non-deterministic I cannot easily reproduce it.

```c
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typdef struct ising_t
{
    float temperature;
    int length;
    int **ensmeble;
} ising_t;


ising_t init_ising_t(int length, float temperature)
{
    int **ensemble = (int**) calloc(length, sizeof(int*));
    for (int col = 0; col < length; col++)
    {
        ensemble[col] = (int*) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < length; col++)
        {
            ensemble[row][col]=rand() / RAND_MAX > 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    
    ising_t system = (ising_t*) malloc(sizeof(ising_t));
    system -> length = length;
    system -> temperature = temperature;
    system -> ensemble = ensemble;
    return system;
}


int main(void)
{
    float start_temp = 1.0;
    float stop_temp = 4.0;
    float temp_step = 1.0;
    int num_temps = (int) ((stop_temp - start_temp) / temp_step);
    ising_t *system;
    for (int num = 20; num < 100; num += num)
    {
        // I want to initialise it here because I am simulating cooling so I want
        // each subsequent iteration of the loop to start at the final state of 
        // the previous iteration and I think that this is the problem. 
        system = init_system(num, stop_temp);
        float* result = (float*) calloc(num_temps, sizeof(float));
        for (float temp_ind = 0; temp_ind < num_temps; temp_ind++)
        {        
            #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) firstprivate(system) 
            for (int _ = 0; _ < big_num; _++)
            {
                expensive_calc(system); 
            }
            result[temp_ind] = final_calculation(system);
            temperature = stop_temp - (temp_ind + 1) * temp_step;
            system -> temperature = temperature;
        }
    }

}
```

As I mentioned in the comment I want the initial state of the next *lower* temperature to match the final state of the current *higher* temperature. I understand that `firstprivate` creates a copy of the `*ising_t` but the same memory location is pointed to and hence `**int`. I really want to copy the entire `struct` and treat it independently on each thread before reassigning `system` in the global scope at the end to match the last/first independent thread that finished. Is there any way to do this like `lastprivate`. I have tried `lastprivate` but it was an instant `segmentation fault`. Would I be better to manually copy the `**ensemble` with a clause like,

```c
if (_ == big_num - 1) { // Magic copy code assigning thread local system to system; }
```

Thanks

Jordan

Comment: I think the pointer is copied, not the structure itself. See https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu106.html . You can perform the copy manually in the parallel loop. Note that C does not have any mechanism so to call a custom function for structure copies as opposed to C++. Thus you need to write a copy function if you want a copy to be done. Since the result of the thread certainly matters, I advise you to declare an array of `ising_t` structure and let each thread operate on its own cell (and then read the array after the parallel loop).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I think, you should have posted it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard. I'm new to posting on Stack-Overflow but I would mark the comment as answered if you re-posted it (if that is a thing). Also FYI on the question I tracked the `segmentation fault` down using `Valgrind` and in the end it was a random index generation in `expensive_calc`, that I didn't spot because I was changing loop iteration numbers while debugging.